# (Left) Joining multiple Tables for Dashboard with several shared Conditions/Filters

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula

Goal: Interactive dashboard with data from different sheets but for the same campaigns.

I got 3+ tables with social media Data in them. I want to combine them by unique ID. Additionally, the users of the dashboard should be able to filter by (partial) ID and dates.

- source tables are split by date > master table has aggregated data but should be filterable by user entered dates
- source tables are of different size and column names
- data should be joined by unique ID (=campaign name)
- optional: master table should be filterable with several keywords for IDs (e.g. "Campaign 1" + "Camp*")
- The campaign list would be built with unique IDs from the Facebook data (the only sheet that contains all campaigns) or another list.

```
Start Date: JJJJ-MM-DD
End Date  : JJJJ-MM-DD
Campaign-Filter: *abc

           |    Facebook    |    Twitter     |    Instagram   |
Total      | _______|_______|________|_______|________|_______|
           | Clicks | Reach | Clicks | Reach | Clicks | Reach |
Campaign 1 |        |       |        |       |        |       |
Campaign 2 |        |       |        |       |        |       |
```

This can be done with SUMIFs but I think query with vlookups would be the better (performing) choice to join the tables. I also liked the idea of replacing col with table names, but formulas get quite complex that way. Can you help me out here?

Comment: Welcome. Questions on this site should be specific, so please make one question post for each of them. Also add a brief description of your search/research efforts as i suggested in [ask]. Tip: Prepare a demo spreadsheet shared with anyone with the link to view only. This demo spreadsheet should contain only the minimum sheets and formulas required to show where to you get stuck.

Comment: I am afraid @Rubén is correct in all points. To summarize, users in this site help each other. No-one is here to just do your job. _(just a friendly nudge to the right direction)_